# How to handle database modifications via Power Apps?

Tags: microsoft-teams, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

First of all, I would like to say please do not be surprised by my question cause I'm a beginner in this sphere.

I just started work with Power Apps and I have the following task:
I need to create some "Notification Service" which will be sent the notification inside Teams group after the event in the SQL table (for example, after successful insert into table).

Could you please explain, is it possible to do via Power Apps features without writing a code?
The application must be work in background mode and automatically send information about new rows in DB.

Any your answer will be very helpful for me!

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Are you familiar with Power Automate? It has an option to notify a user directly in Teams as a step in a workflow

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow thanks for your answer, I don't have experience in Power Automate. 

As I see this option allows realize notifications based on customized conditions for rows based on DB. I think it's a good solution to achieve my target. 

If you have any advice or helpful information I will be grateful.

Thanks for your answer again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerApps doesn't have the ability to notify people this way. You have to use Power Automate. A flow can be triggered when a row is changed or modified. In order to trigger a Flow on a database, the database field must have a TimeStamp field and a primary key.